# Selective Data Export in JSON from Sling Model Exporter in AEM?

Tags: java, aem, sling-models

I have successfully implemented a Sling model exporter, but I'm facing an issue where the entire dataset, including unwanted information like null values, is being exported in JSON. How can I ensure that only the relevant data, excluding the unwanted details, is shared through the JSON exporter in AEM? Are there any specific annotation I can apply to achieve this selective data export or  is it possible at this level of implementation?

This is how my output looks like

{"Hello":{"location":"pune","name":"john","surname":"h",”phonenumber”:”null”}}

In the above output Phone number data has null .so,I don’t want to export that can you please help on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to achieve using `@JSONIgnore`. Here's a sample code snippet

```
@Exporter(
    name = "jackson", extensions = "json", selector = "geeks",
)
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL, resourceType = "wknd/components/hello")
public class Hello {

    @ValueMapValue
    private String imagesrc;

    public String getImagesrc() {
        return null;
    }

    @ValueMapValue
    private String imagetitle;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getImagetitle() {
        return imagetitle;
    }

}
```

---

##### Output

`{"imagetitle":"kotlin"}`

---

This annotation is used to indicate that a specific field or method should be ignored during the JSON serialization and deserialization process. It helps exclude certain properties from being included in the JSON output.

In the above example, `imagesrc` is null so it is not exporting in JSON format.

If you want to learn about JSON annotations go through it [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)